# Selecting elements by class when they have multiple classes?

Tags: xpath, domxpath

Consider the following HTML:

```
<span class="foo">foo</span>
```

When searching for elements with a single class, the XPath syntax is pretty nice:

```
@class="foo"
```

However, the above syntax doesn't work when the element has more than one class:

```
<span class="foo bar">foo bar</span>
```

The only syntax I've found for this situation is this:

```
contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " foo ")
```

This is nasty! Query strings quickly become ridiculously long with this method.

Is there an easier way to search for elements with more than one class?

Answer (score 1):

If a class contains a space, it should contain more than one class

with this input:

```
<span class="foo bar">foo bar</span>
```

and this query

```
contains(normalize-space(span/@class), " ")
```

the output is

```
true
```

Comment: I actually meant selecting an element with a specific class when it has multiple classes. So, for example, selecting elements with class "foo" when the element has the classes "foo" and "bar". My question's title was worded poorly though, so thanks for trying..

Comment: It's just a matter of adding another `contains` and checking the class separately. I'm sure Joel will fix this, but it will be longer than your version.